# Escape Characters in Scala Play configuration files

Tags: playframework, escaping, properties-file

I want to be able to define a property as a json-string within `application.conf` of my web app, like the one below:

```
prop1 = "{key1:value1 , key2:value2}"
```

However, the values in my case have double quotes within, and '\' doesn't work as an escape character. How can I declare the json within prop1, with double quotes inside them, something like

```
prop1 = "{key1 : \"value1\", key2:\"value2\" }"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Play is using the typesafe config library under the hood and hence the HOCON format you can use multiline strings:

```
prop1 = """{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }"""
```

See https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#multi-line-strings

Comment: WoW! That was incredibly simple :) Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Just being curious, what to do if I want to introduce the three quote stirng """ ?? Agreed that its likely to never be of use in a real scenario, still wondering if there's a way.